# Pipe to executable without exiting/EOF in bash

Tags: bash, sh

I have a (read-only) executable "myexec" which I always execute followed by the input "input1" (a string), and then I get on with my business "" and "exit" when I feel like it:

```
$ myexec
> input1
> do something else for as long as I like
> exit
```

What I would like to do is *automatically* execute "myexec" with the input "input1", and then be able to "do something else for as long as I like". From what I can see, my options are:

```
$ myexec <<< "input1"
```

or

```
$ echo "input1" | myexec
```

or

```
$ myexec << EOF
input1
EOF
```

BUT the problem with these methods is that they terminate "myexec" after reading "input1". How can I avoid the EOF/exit/terminate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [expect](/questions/tagged/expect) to automate that. For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn /my/exec
expect "> "
send "input1\r"
interact
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `cat` for this:

```
$ { echo "input1"; cat; } | my exec
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a `pipe` and listen for inputs with `tail -f`

```
mkfifo pipe
tail -f pipe | ./script.sh
```

Example content of script.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

while read row
do
    if [ "${row}" = "exit" ]; then
        break
    fi
    echo "ROW READ $row"
done

echo "script exit"
exit 0
```

Then, with another script, feed the pipe

```
echo "example content" > ./pipe
echo "bla bla bla" > ./pipe
echo "exit" > ./pipe
echo "" > ./pipe
```

you'll obtain

```
[root@mypc ~]# tail -f pipe | ./script
ROW READ example content
ROW READ bla bla bla
script exit
[root@mypc ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

It almost sounds like you want a fifo, which is a named pipe stored in your filesystem. Any output you redirect to it will come out the other side into what is listening.  Try this:

```
mkfifo myexec.fifo
myexec < myexec.fifo &
echo input1 > myexec.fifo
echo input2 > myexec.fifo
```

You can test this by using bash and having it run commands that are sent to the fifo, in the example below:

```
mkfifo bash.fifo
/bin/bash < bash.fifo &
echo uname > bash.fifo
Darwin
```

The ampersand detaches the process into the background, so as long as myexec continues to listen it'll continue to execute commands.

If myexec is exiting, you can wrap it in a while loop:

```
while [ 1 ]; do myexec < myexec.fifo; done
```

After myexec consumes the contents of what is waiting in the fifo, it will iterate the loop. If the fifo is empty, it will wait.

Comment: The problem with this is that I would like to interact with objects created in "myexec" (X-forwarded processes) which disappear as soon as they are created with this method... I.e I would like this method but without detaching it!